# Is AJAX push a HTTP protocol aberration?

Tags: ajax, http, web-applications, design-principles

Develop a elegant Pub-Sub architecture in web-oriented-apps is a real challenge.
Although there are some very interesting solutions using long-polling-connections (e.g. COMET) and repetitive-timeouts (e.g. js setTimeout). IMHO AJAX push still looking like a layer of tweaks and hacks forcing the innocent HTTP protocol.

So what do you think **Is AJAX push a HTTP protocol aberration?**

**Which others alternatives you could consider in a web architecture?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option I've seen used before is to use a small hidden Java or Flash to connect via plain sockets to the remote server. The server can then push data / events over these sockets at any time, without any polling from the client.

Flash is a little better IMO since it doesn't require a signed applet (which pops up security warnings for the user). It's had Sockets in one form or another for something like 9 years now, though it wasn't until Flash 9 / AS3 that you got 'pure' sockets that you could use to connect to any type of service (previously it required that messages be terminated with a 'null' packet, meaning you had to design your protocol specifically for flash, instead of being able to use XMPP or SMTP or any existing protocol)

Answer (score 4):

> Which others alternatives you could
>   consider in a web architecture?

The HTML 5 [Web Sockets API](http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/) and [Server-sent Events](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/2007-10-26/multipage/section-server-sent-events.html#server-sent-events) look promising for the future. No IE support for Web Sockets yet, and Server-sent Events are still experimental. Douglas Crockford's [JSONRequest](http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html) proposal would also be an interesting alternative to AJAX push, but it is not yet implemented in modern browsers.

For the present, I'll stick with [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)).

Answer (score 2):

Polling is the web-architecture way of doing pub-sub. It works well when clients poll infrequently and the responses can be cached and shared (for example, the rss feed of a blog). Keeping a tcp socket open per client, like with comet, is not the ideal way of using http. However, if your app runs in a web browser, and needs frequent, unique, per-client updates, that's not a bad way of doing it.

Comet and polling for per-client resources are not completely abusive to http or the web -- it's just that http and the web were designed particularly to share the same resources (ie web pages) among many clients, so that's the way it works best.

Answer (score 1):

Just think about the most common Comet implementations,  just the fact that you have to fool the browser into thinking that it's receiving a multipart response or an infinitely long html inside an iframe is enough to raise a flag on whether this is the appropriate technology or not for the job.